# Numpy: Wav to list and then back again creates garbage

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, wav

I'm using Python 3.7 and am currently developing a solution that requires me to convert a WAV file to a Numpy Array, then to a List, then back to an Array, and finally written again as a WAV file. Earlier today, it was able to convert and then reconvert with no issues. However, it is currently returning a WAV file that is listenable but is entirely static.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
```

...

```
rate, data = wavfile.read(os.path.join(F_IN_FOLDER, f))
work = data.tolist()
out = np.array(work, dtype=np.float32)
wavfile.write(os.path.join(F_IN_FOLDER, f), rate, out)
```

The purpose of this code is so that, as a list, I can silence portions of the WAV file and then write over the original file. I am inexperienced with WAV files as well as the Numpy library, and if there is a more efficient way to this this, I'm interested in learning it.

Comment: What's `data.dtype`?

Comment: Here's the documentation - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html . As far as I know, it's a way to format the conversion into a numpy array. In its current state, the output is garbage, but if I set it to any other data type, the resulting WAV file becomes unplayable.

Comment: Thequestion was when you run data.dtype, what is the output?

Comment: ...I am an idiot. The files were int16, not float32. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to convert the array to a list in the first place though? Sounds like a really bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @NilsWerner - you should be able to do everything as numpy array's and much faster than working with it as a list. I'm not sure what you mean by "silence", but assuming for the moment that this involves writing zeroes to particular parts of the array then you could do something like:

```
# create an array of 1's (my sample test data)
a = np.ones(10)

# zero out a specific range of indices using standard numpy slice notation.
a[5:8] = 0

# check the result
print(a)
```

and get back

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
```

check out the numpy documentation at [numpy slices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) and the related scipy documentation [scipy indexing](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html).